# Update VirtualBox without losing Guest .vdi Files

Tags: macos, windows, software-update, unix, virtualbox

I have **VirtualBox** "Version 5.1.4 r110228 (Qt5.5.1)" installed on a MacBook Air **macOS Sierra version 10.12**. Now I got an update message: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.6/VirtualBox-5.1.6-110634-OSX.dmg

But how can I update my VirtualBox version from **5.1.4** to **5.1.6**? Obviously without losing my guests installations *CentOS 7 64* and *Windows 10 Enterprise*.

Do I need to remove VirtualBox 5.1.4? And what happens with my Guest VDI installations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shut down all VMs and quit VirtualBox. Open VirtualBox-5.1.6-110634-OSX.dmg and double-click the installer in the mounted image. The installer will overwrite the old VirtualBox.app and some other files.

The VMs will be kept in place and won't be modified.

Later download the latest Extension Pack 5.1.6-110634 and install it in the existing VMs if necessary/possible.